# .htaccess commands are case insensitive?

Tags: .htaccess

I see the same .htaccess code snippet written with two different ways as follows:

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

and

```
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

I'm I right to assume both versions are equally valid? Are all .htaccess commands case insensitive?

Comment: It depend of your apache version, on apache 2.4 both are false

Comment: See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html

Comment: @Froggiz I'm surprized! I have seen them suggested by many sites/guides. After doing some research, I guess you mean that the "deny from all" line could be omitted?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/upgrading.html in `Run-Time Configuration Changes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Order, Allow, Deny`: those are called apache directives, and these three belong to `mod_authz_host` module (as of Apache 2.1 and later versions). In principle the apache directives are case-insensitive, so both are valid. See [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/configuring.html):

> **Directives in the configuration files are case-insensitive**, but
>   arguments to directives are often case sensitive. Lines that begin
>   with the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored.
>   Comments may not be included on the same line as a configuration
>   directive. White space occurring before a directive is ignored, so you
>   may indent directives for clarity. Blank lines are also ignored.

Comment: Very helpful :)